# How can I use a drawn rectangle by myself as a button

Tags: android

You know that if we want to use a button in android, we use the following code:

```
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, B.class);
startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Now my question is if I draw a rectangle by myself, can I use the `MotionEvent` class for this purpose? If it is possible so how is it? I wrote the following code to draw a rectangle. Now I want that the rectangle behaviors like the button in the above code.

```
public class B extends View {
  Paint paint;
B(Context context) {
   super(context);
    paint = new Paint();
    }
@Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
canvas.drawRect(10,20,40,100,paint);

}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    return true; // I am a little confused in this section in spite of searching in internet.
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign on `OnClickListener` to any View, not just Buttons. You don't need to override `onTouchEvent()`.

Alternatively, you can use a regular Button (or just a View even) and just give a solid rectangle as a background drawable.

Comment: Thank you. But the problem is that the button can use the `OnClickListener`  method because this method there is in `Button` class. But `Canvas` class has not the `OnClickListener` method.

Comment: @android Any View can have an `OnClickListener`. Your class `B` extends View, so you can set an `OnClickListener` on it just the same.